# generate a java bean from a JSON file with jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am working with javaFX, I need to generate dynamically java beans from a JSON file, so I want that my jackson parser the JSON file and transform it to a java bean with its attributs and getters & setters.
Is that possible?

Comment: try this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I am not looking for any tools. I am looking for an API or any thing can help me to code it with javaFX and jackson

Comment: How are you going to use this beans? Could you provide some example about it?

Comment: every bean has its java FX interface (fxml file) so the input gonna be a json file from that file java beans are generated with its fxml files